# Finishing this snippet of code to pass data via a segue from one controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have a ViewController, "ViewController".

Within this view there is an attribute 'userEmailText.text' that I want to pass along to another view controller, "CreateNewCommunity"

I have a button connected to a segue with identifier 'createCommunitySegue'.  I have create the code for when this is tapped:

```
@IBAction func createCommunityTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createCommunitySegue", sender: self)   
}
```

In my second view controller, "CreateNewCommunity" I have a variable:

```
var myEmail: String?
```

and I have started to build the code ready to receive the data from the segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "createCommunitySegue" {
            let createCommunityController: CreateNewCommunity = segue.destination as! CreateNewCommunity
            createCommunityController.myEmail =
        }

    }
```

How do I finish this set-up so that the initial 'userEmailText.text' value is passed by "ViewController" through segue 'createCommunitySegue' into "CreateNewCommunity" view controller?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just do `createCommunityController.myEmail = userEmailText.text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just

```
createCommunityController.myEmail = userEmailText.text
```

I think your problem is that you have a wrong idea of how to pass data from one vc to another.

The VC that you are passing data *to* doesn't *recieve* the data. It is the VC that has the data proactively pass the data to the VC that needs it.

My guess would be that you put this code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "createCommunitySegue" {
        let createCommunityController: CreateNewCommunity = segue.destination as! CreateNewCommunity
        createCommunityController.myEmail =
    }

}
```

in the `CreateNewCommunity` controller! You should instead put the above in `ViewController` not `CreateNewCommunity` , and write

```
createCommunityController.myEmail = userEmailText.text
```

it should work.

Comment: could you please edit this as the 'But no, that's not correct' comment has confused me.  Can you please just show me what is correct?  Thank you.

Comment: @RichardDowns  basically, put the prepareForSegue method in the VC that initiates the segue, I.e. `ViewController`

Comment: Thank you Sweeper - that's fixed it. :)

Comment: @RichardDowns if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark.

Answer (score 0):

VC1

```
@IBAction func createCommunityTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createCommunitySegue", sender: self)   
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "createCommunitySegue" {
        let createCommunityController: CreateNewCommunity = segue.destination as! CreateNewCommunity
        createCommunityController.myEmail = userEmailText.text
    }

}
```

VC2

```
var myEmail: String?
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


 print(myEmail)
 }
```